# How to separate the band structure of different materials in heterostructures using Quantum ESPRESSO?

Tags: quantum-espresso, band-structure, 2d-lattice, graphene, heterostructures

So, I know that to calculate surface band structure of a material, you have to take its 2D system eg. *single or few-layered*. But, how to find the surface band structure in the case of heterostructures. This paper does it ["Proximity-induced topological state in graphene
"](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.90.035418) but uses **VASP** instead. Is it possible to do the same using **Quantum espresso**?

Thank you

Comment: +1. You have to post 7 more questions or answers in the next 24 hours to fulfill commitment: https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/208058/ashique-lal. Do you think you can do it please? :)

Comment: Well, 2D system is not a surface. A surface is a semi-infinity system (periodic in two directions and with a vacuum layer on the other direction).

Comment: @NikeDattani Its 11 questions now. Am i late? :(

Comment: It had to be done within the first 6 months, so now it says that you have no "current commitments" and no "fulfilled commitments": https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/208058/. This is what it looks like if you have fulfilled commitment: https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/190792/nike-dattani?tab=stats. Here you can see that we're now in our 181st day in Beta: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/matter-modeling, which means 6 months is over!

Answer (score 6):

I believe what you are referring to is a "projected" or "fat" band structure diagram. By assigning colors (or line thickness) to a basis on which you project the Kohn-Sham states (pseudoatomic orbitals, Wannier functions, etc.) you can plot the band structure in a way that shows the composition of all the states in the bands in terms of this basis. There are a few ways to do this in Quantum ESPRESSO.

1. This capability has been included for the last few versions in Quantum ESPRESSO itself. Look in the folder
   `q-e/PP/examples/projected_bands_example/`
   for an example that shows how to do this. The projected states you're interested in will be those that correspond to the atoms on your surface. The `projwfc.x` output labels these states according to the atom order you specify in your `ATOMIC_POSITIONS` part of your input file.
2. Other codes that interface with QE can generate projected band structures. One example is [LOBSTER](http://schmeling.ac.rwth-aachen.de/cohp/index.php?menuID=6). See section 3 of the user's guide. [Wannier90](http://www.wannier.org/features/) can also create projected band diagrams in terms of the maximally-localized Wannier functions it generates.